# Air file convert to apps

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air

I convert air application to Air apps using ios certificate[.pk12] format,but this show error message -not a  code signing certificate.how i solved this issue anyone give me a solution for this type of message.[Note-ios certificate is valid upto 2014].here i attach the image,

Saravanan

Answer (score 0):

To build an AIR for iOS app, you must have an Apple iOS Dev account. You create the certificate and mobile provision file in the iOS Dev Portal. Once they are created, you use Keychain Access to convert the .cer file to a .p12 file. I am unsure if you can do that anywhere except Mac. You then use the .p12 file, not a .pk12, to sign your app.

See Adobe's official process for doing this [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WSe4e4b720da9dedb5-2e7310a1136ab7c1811-7fee.html#WSe4e4b720da9dedb5-2e7310a1136ab7c1811-7fec).